# PHP SoapClient - number formatting ignored

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm sending data to a .NET SOAP service. 
For each field in the parameters of the operation, a specific formatting is specified.
For example doubles (`number2dp`) need to have a `0.00` format (2 decimals).

I've formatted all these numbers (as a string) and they seem fine when I call the `SOAPClient`.
I'm using: `SOAPClient->__soapCall(method, parameters)`

At this point, the parameter formatting of the numbers still checks out.

Somewhere in the flow, when the soapclient builds the xml, that formatting is lost.
The xml output shows `<amount>0</amount>` when actually it should be a `<amount>0.00</amount>`
Same with other numbers; 123.90, will format to 123.9

Anyone have an idea how to force the SOAPClient to use the formatted string, and not convert it to a number?

*UPDATE:*
The workaround: a custom PHP SOAP library (eg. NuSOAP) was used to send data to the server.
Beware of memory issues when doing so.
The native SOAPClient was still used to receive & parse data from the server.